# Reading from Serial port with Vive (SteamVR) resulting in huge lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serial-port, steamvr

I am developing a **Forklift simulation in HTC Vive** using the latest **SteamVR plugin (V 2.3.0).** I want to add a custom fabricated **steering wheel** to the sim, which gives **values based on it's rotation**. I already had implemented the simulation controls using Vive controllers and keyboard. But the moment since I added the serial connection reading code, the simulation starts **lagging** bad. 15-20 fps is what I get just by **reading from serial port**.

```
void Awake ()
        {
            InitializeCOMport();
            StartCoroutine(ReadData());
        }

    void InitializeCOMport()
        {
             port = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            try
            {
                port.Open();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                Debug.Log("Port open");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log("Exception " + ex.Message);
            }
    }
    IEnumerator ReadData()
        {
            yield return null;
            do
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15f);
                try
                {
                    datareceived = port.ReadLine().Trim();
                    char[] charsToTrim = { 'd', 'a', 't', ' ', '=' };
                    datareceived = datareceived.Trim(charsToTrim);
                    //Debug.Log("Steering port: " + datareceived);
                    currSteeringValue = int.Parse(datareceived);

                }
                catch(System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Exception " + ex.Message);
                }
            } while (true);
        }
```

I had to read the serial port data this way because when I try doing it using the  `SerialPort.DataReceived` event, I get a time-out exception. With the above Coroutine ReadData() I am able to get the COMM port data, but not using the DataRecieved event. Here is the code that reads the buffer using the event-

```
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);

     private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.Log("received");   //This function is fired with
                try
                {
                    datareceived = port.ReadLine().Trim();
                    char[] charsToTrim = { 'd', 'a', 't', ' ', '=' };
                    datareceived = datareceived.Trim(charsToTrim);
                    Debug.Log("Steering port: " + datareceived);
                    currSteeringValue = int.Parse(datareceived);

                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Exception " + ex.Message);
                }
                Debug.Log("received");
            }
```

The above Port_DataReceived() results in Time-out exception and the control never reaches to `Debug.Log("Steering port: " + datareceived);` this point, as it doesn't get logged.

Is this lag because I am using serial ports with vive? Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

**UPDATE:** Actually I tried using thread too, but it too results in Timeout exception. Here's the code of the thread function and here too the control doesn't reach the Debug.Log(steering) line, and there is a time-out exception.

```
serialThread = new System.Threading.Thread(RecordData);
serialThread.Start();
void RecordData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Trying to read data");
            datareceived = port.ReadLine().Trim();
            //Debug.Log(datareceived);
            char[] charsToTrim = { 'd', 'a', 't', ' ', '=' };
            datareceived = datareceived.Trim(charsToTrim);
            Debug.Log("Steering port: " + datareceived);
            currSteeringValue = int.Parse(datareceived);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exception " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataReceived callback is not implemented in Mono unfortunately, it simply doesn't work, and default pooling method does indeed block the thread. The solution is to start another thread just for com port handling.

Comment: Actually I tried using thread too, but it too results in Timeout exception. Please refer the Update section of the question.